# gpg-agent and SSH: No keys

Tags: ssh, gnupg

I'm trying to enable SSH authentication through my GPG subkey, using [this tutorial](http://incenp.org/notes/2015/gnupg-for-ssh-authentication.html). However, I borrowed and used the `.init` script from [this blog](https://blog.night-shade.org.uk/2015/04/ssh-support-in-gpg-agent-on-ubunt/) (in lieu of editing my Xprofile).

However, I'm getting a very peculiar error message:

```
┌─[12:53:49]─[user@pc]
└──> ~ $ ssh-add -l
gpg-agent[7659]: ssh handler 0xABCD1234 for fd 5 started
gpg-agent[7659]: ssh request 1 is not supported
gpg-agent[7659]: ssh request handler for request_identities (11) started
gpg-agent[7659]: no running SCdaemon - starting it
gpg-agent[7659]: DBG: first connection to SCdaemon established
gpg-agent[7659]: no authentication key for ssh on card: Card error
gpg-agent[7659]: /home/user/.gnupg/sshcontrol:4: key '[keygrip from auth key]' skipped: No such file or directory
gpg-agent[7659]: ssh request handler for request_identities (11) ready
The agent has no identities.
gpg-agent[7659]: ssh handler 0xABCD1234 for fd 5 terminated
```

This, of course, makes no sense because I have never used a smartcard, nor do I think I have smartcard drivers installed.

Additionally, these GPG keys are valid and are imported. The key listed above also does have an authentication subkey.

I am running GnuPG version 2.1.1.

Is there any way to fix this, and (as a bonus), get my SSH keys working through GPG?

---

Contents of `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol`:

```
# List of allowed ssh keys.  Only keys present in this file are used
# in the SSH protocol.  The ssh-add tool may add new entries to this

<keygrip from my auth key>
```

---

**Edit:** Upon doing `set | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, I get:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-PLDuNs/ssh
```

However, upon trying to `cat` this file, I get a `No such device or address` error. However, I'm not sure if this is relevant or just user error by expecting a return.

Comment: What do you have in your `/home/user/.gnupg/sshcontrol`? It looks like something broken there.

Comment: @Jakuje Edited to show (censored) contents.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place? Why don't you use normal ssh keys and normal ssh-agent in the first place?

Comment: @Jakuje I'm trying to swap over to using my GPG authentication key for SSH logins from now on. And, when I eventually do move over to a smartcard, I'll be able to use that for SSH logins.

Comment: Fair enough. I would like to give it a try some time also. Maybe tomorrow. For bonus, you can add the keys just using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` or where they are (if you don't have the `gpg-agent` totally messed up).

Comment: `ssh-add -l` requests `gpg-agent` to list _all_ available keys -- this includes checking a smartcard if there is one. It looks like `gpg-agent` finds a smart card, but cannot talk with it. Try adding `disable-scdaemon` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and restart `gpg-agent`. Don't forget to remove that option once you've got an OpenPGP smartcard.

Comment: @JensErat I tried that, and it returns the same thing, just without the smartcard error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two problems with your setup:

1. > However, I borrowed and used the `.init` script from this blog (in lieu of editing my Xprofile).

   The init script from that blog post is outdated (*i.e.,* for versions of GnuPG prior to 2.1). Don't use it.
2. > **Edit:** Upon doing `set | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, I get:
   >
   > ```
   > SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-PLDuNs/ssh
   > ```
   >
   > However, upon trying to cat this file, I get a No such device or address error. However, I'm not sure if this is relevant or just user error by expecting a return.

   You're using the wrong SSH auth socket.

For a source on these claims, consult [the official documentation](https://gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html). For a straight fix, see [Jens Erat’s outline of the process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373963/176219) on the Unix StackExchange. Copied here for convenience:

> 1. enable the `ssh-agent` protocol by adding `enable-ssh-support` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`
> 2. `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh`; you might want to do that in your `~/.profile`
> 3. kill `ssh-agent` if started and reload `gpg-agent` (`gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`)
> 4. export and add your public key to target servers (`ssh-add -L` should now contain the familiar SSH public key line for your OpenPGP key)
>
>    *Editor's Note: This step can be simplified by [adding the key's ‘keygrip’ value to `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` and then authorizing it on the remote server with `ssh-copy-id`](http://ryanlue.com/posts/2017-06-29-gpg-for-ssh-auth#adding-keys).*
> 5. `ssh` to the target server as with a normal SSH key